# How to use node-walk with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, directory-walk, node-walk

[Node walk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk) presents an API with a few events like this.

```
walker.on('file', (root, filestats, next) => {
  // next should be called to goto next file
  next();
});
walker.on('end', () => {
  // the end of the stream
});
```

Is it reactive if from the `subscriber` you're calling a function to inform the `source` to go to the next item in the stream ? Events don't wait for the subscriber to react to it, right ?

How do I transform this into a Rx Observable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a wrapper around it:

```
Rx.Observable.fromWalk = function(root, options, scheduler) {
  scheduler = scheduler || Rx.Scheduler.currentThread;

  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var walker = walk.walk(root, options);

    function fileHandler(x) {
      observer.onNext({stats : x.stats, root : x.root});
      scheduler.scheduleWithState(x, function(s, i) {
        i.next();
      });
    }

    var files = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(walker, 'file', 
      function(arr) {
        return { root : arr[0], stats : arr[1], next : arr[2] };
    });
    var ended = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(walker, 'end');

    return new Rx.CompositeDisposable(
      files.subscribe(fileHandler),
      ended.subscribe(observer.onCompleted.bind(observer))
    );
  });
};
```

I updated your [example](http://runnable.com/VWC95roUO3YLEN5t/rx-walk-for-node-js-and-hello-world) accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Rx.Observable.fromCallback`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromcallback.md):

```
var walkerOn = Rx.Observable.fromCallback(walker.on, walker)
var source = walkerOn('file');
var subscription = source.subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: http://runnable.com/VWC95roUO3YLEN5t/rx-walk-for-node-js-and-hello-world 
What am I missing ?

Comment: @BoopathiRajaa It would appear the callback needs to be called with `walker` as context. So either use `bind` or provide `walker` as the second argument to `fromCallback`.

Comment: That worked. But the problem is I guess a callback is fired only once. So only the first found item is resolved, and immediately completed.